# Why is lstlisting splitting my XML tags?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, xml, sharelatex

I have a little problem with this ambient. I have some XML to insert into my document and the thing that really bugs me is that the new line breaks a closing tag in two. I indicated to the environment that I am using XML but to no use. This is the code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XML]
<ce:bib-reference id="BIB14">
    <ce:label>[14]</ce:label>
    <ce:other-ref>
        <ce:textref>W. Mitchell, How weak is the closed, unbounded filter?, Preprint.</ce:textref>
    </ce:other-ref>
</ce:bib-reference>
\end{lstlisting}
```

The tag `</ce:textref>` is split into `</` on the first line and `ce:textref>` on the second. This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true,escapeinside={~*}{*~}}
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ariel, your should post your code in one piece; don't break it apart (preamble here, body there) because people who want to test it have to (tediously) piece it back together. Besides, I can't reproduce the problematic line break you report. Could you post or link to a screenshot of the output?

Comment: Please complete your code. We still don't know which document class you're using. If I simply use `article`, I don't get the problematic line break you mentioned.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem. Have you tried updating your TeX distribution?

Comment: I am using www.sharelatex.com

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use option `breakatwhitespace`

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines,
        escapeinside={~*}{*~},
        breakatwhitespace}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the OP already uses `breaklines` in the preamble because he reports a line break in the output, and `listings` doesn't effect any line break unless option `breaklines` is set.

Comment: I think the `breakatwhitespace` option is just what I was looking for. Many thanks!